# what is the basic configuration of sdk and xcode to use core telephony?

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

what is the basic configuration of sdk and xcode to use core telephony and message composer framework in our application? i have xcode 3.2.2 and sdk 3.2.4, can i use these frameworks with this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK 3.2.4 makes no sense for iPhone.

Core Telephony is 4.0 or later, Message Composer as well (Mail Composer is 3.x).

You should update your tools to their latest versions anyway, no matter what OS version you target. But those features won't be available prior to 4.0.